# Why Hangfire doesn't process recurring jobs in parallel?

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have 30 recurring jobs. Every job just writes it's id in console, does nothing more. Every job is programmed to recurrently run every second.

```
SchedulePollingInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
WorkerCount = 100
```

According to the log in console every job is started approximately every 30 seconds.
Why not every second? 
When there is only one single job configured, then it runs every second as expected. The more jobs are the longer delay between runs.
Is it possible to configure Hangfire to run multiple jobs every second?

Hangfire is running in ASP.NET Core 3.1 environment with SQL server backend.

Comment: Please attach you cron expression as well.

Comment: cron expression "*/1 * * * * *" every second